# labels disappearing in pgfplot bar chart

Tags: pgfplots

Only the third label appears for this bar chart. If I put only one data row, the label shows up fine. If I put two data rows, both the labels are hidden. If I put three data rows (as below), only the third label shows up.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
X   question                                                                interactionhigh InteractionLow  VisualHigh  VisualLow
1   {*I needed to learn a lot of material before I could get started with SIDNIE.}      6.50                6.18                6.22            5.96
2   {I felt very confident working with SIDNIE.}                                    5.60                5.55                6.11            6.04
3   {*I found the system very cumbersome for use.}                          6.50                6.64                6.44            5.62
}\datatable

  \begin{axis}[xbar=0,
   yticklabels from table={\datatable}{question},
   y tick label style={text width=5cm, align=right},
height=18cm,
width=10cm,
inner sep=0mm,
xmin=0,
xmax=7,
  ]

\addplot table[y=X,x={interactionhigh}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={InteractionLow}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={VisualHigh}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={VisualLow}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either explicitly specify which ticks to use (by saying `ytick={1,...,3}`), or specify to only label coordinates with data, by saying `ytick=data`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
X   question                                                                interactionhigh InteractionLow  VisualHigh  VisualLow
1   {*I needed to learn a lot of material before I could get started with SIDNIE.}      6.50                6.18                6.22            5.96
2   {I felt very confident working with SIDNIE.}                                    5.60                5.55                6.11            6.04
3   {*I found the system very cumbersome for use.}                          6.50                6.64                6.44            5.62
}\datatable

  \begin{axis}[xbar=0,
   yticklabels from table={\datatable}{question},
   y tick label style={text width=5cm, align=right},
y=2cm, enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
width=10cm,
xmin=0,
xmax=7,
ytick=data,
  ]

\addplot table[y=X,x={interactionhigh}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={InteractionLow}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={VisualHigh}] {\datatable};
\addplot table[y=X,x={VisualLow}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```